# Android: GoogleMaps SearchView in a fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio, searchview

I started to build an application yesterday that uses fragments in a ViewPager. I currently have one main activity with the ViewPager, two fragments (that are loaded to main activity pager) and a navigation drawer. The contents are empty, I just started to work on the first fragment. What I want it to do is to have a background of a google map, and a SearchView above it. This is what it looks like (link):

[IMG - The first fragment with the map and searchview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Put2m.jpg)

I never worked with Google Maps API, so this is kinda difficult for me. I simply want to make the search function work by suggesting the places and showing the place on map after selection (similar functionality that google maps has).

I checked and tried about 8 solutions from the stackoverflow and the rest of the internet, I finally got to the point where I don't get any exceptions or fatal errors, but the suggestions and searching doesn't work yet. Below I post my code from the files that have something to do with it, hope it will help you to find what is wrong with my code. I bet it's more than just one line, so I would like to thanks in advance to anyone who will spend any time by helping me.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.marto.findparking.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".ActivityHome">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="...hidden..." />
    <provider
        android:name=".gmaps.PlaceProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.marto.findparking.gmaps.search_suggestion_provider"
        android:exported="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

searchable.xml

```
<searchable ...

android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.marto.findparking.gmaps.search_suggestion_provider"
android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
android:searchSuggestThreshold="2" >
</searchable>
```

fragment_activity_home_parameter.xml (fragment that im working on)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
         >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/show_menu_icon"/>

            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
            </SearchView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/searchViewResult"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

ActivityHome.java (main activity)

```
public class ActivityHome extends AppCompatActivity {
public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_home);
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_home_parameter, null);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    // Tells your app's SearchView to use this activity's searchable configuration
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
}
```

}

The last thing I used are the files from this tutorial:
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-google-places-api-using-actionbarsherlock-library/
We're talking about classes with names PlaceDetailsJSONParser, PlaceJSONParser and PlaceProvider. The thing is that I'm pretty sure that by this point I mixed a lot of things together, so some parts of the code may not event belong to where they are. I also read, that there is no way to use searchview functionality inside of a fragment, and that it needs to be done differently, by programming a SearchActivity class and passing data from here to the fragment. Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Comment: where do you need help ? in xml ?

Comment: @SagarNayak Im not sure where the mistake is, so I need someone to review the code and tell me what could be wrong, so I can try further

Comment: ok . tell me what do you want your code to do ? what functionality you want in your code ?

Comment: @SagarNayak I want to have a searchview inside of a fragment and use it for location search using google maps API

Comment: so why dont you use the placeautocomplete fragment here ?

Comment: @SagarNayak instead of searchview? does it work the same way?

Comment: this is recommended by google. so it works the best .